# close reason doesn't match

Tags: support

I was reviewing [Remote workstation management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564984/remote-workstation-management?noredirect=1) and chose "too broad" as a closure reason. For some reason it now shows I chose "unclear what your asking" Is this a "bug", a "feature" or what? I make it a point to do my own analysis and don't blindly agree with previous close voters so I found the result confusing.

Comment: The majority opinion is always shown as the reason. :( See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181870/270345

Comment: Thank you. My apologies for the duplicate question. I couldn't find a match....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you votes there was one "too broad" vote and three "unclear" votes. Your "too broad" vote was the vote it needed to close it but the end result was 3-2 to "unclear".

I agree that this might seem confusing and would probably benefit from a little message if you're the deciding vote and it splits against you, but the actual behaviour is by design.

Comment: By design works for me... Thanks I'm filing this under "feature"